# Email validation getting System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

when the entry box is empty and I pressed the button. I get this error message System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input' I tried many ways to figure out

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        listmembers.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetMemberAsync();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var email = loginEmail.Text;
        var emailpattern = @"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$";


        if (Regex.IsMatch(email, emailpattern))
        {
            await App.Database.SaveMemberAsync(new Member
            {
                Name = loginEmail.Text,
            });
            loginEmail.Text =  string.Empty;
            listmembers.ItemsSource = await 
                App.Database.GetMemberAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Invaild Email", "ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Presumably one of your method calls is passing in a null value - but we don't have the full stack trace, so we don't know which method is failing. (It might not even be a method you're calling directly.) Please show the *complete* stack trace.

Comment: you need to check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)` before attempting to use it

Comment: This *isn't* a duplicate of the NullReferenceException question - ArgumentNullException is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to test for null

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && Regex.IsMatch(email, emailpattern))
```

Comment: Thank you it  works. what if i did this way if             ' else if (!Regex.IsMatch(email, emailpattern))
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Invaild Email", "ok");
            } ' and gives me System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: the exception occurs because you are passing a null`email` object to `Regex.IsMatch` .  That's why you need to test for null **before** you call `Regex.IsMatch`

Comment: It makes sense now thank you very much